# How do I get the last two letters by skipping first letter of a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the column say `name` in a table:

```
Name 
--------   
Suresh   
Krishna  
Kamal
```

Expected output would be

```
es  
hn  
ma
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get a chance to check T-SQL manual , you have right function there http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx

Comment: **(1)** find the [MSDN documentation on T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741.aspx), **(2)** read about the string functions, **(3)** try out some code, **(4)** --> Done!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you

```
Select LEFT( RIGHT(Name,3),2) from Table1
```

Comment: Thanks Mendez , it helped me lot .